# Why Is a migration file created (over and over) when i run makemigrations

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Am facing a somehow funny issue...every time i migrate,i get this description

```
  Your models in app(s): 'organization_app' have changes that are not yet reflected in a migration, and so won't be applied.
  Run 'manage.py makemigrations' to make new migrations, and then re-run 'manage.py migrate' to apply them.
```

so i follow what django says and i makemigrations,this migration file is created

```py
# Generated by Django 4.2.3 on 2024-02-07 20:14

from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    dependencies = [
        ("organization_app", "0002_alter_penaltymodel_tenant_penalty_choice"),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name="penaltymodel",
            name="tenant_penalty_choice",
            field=models.CharField(
                choices=[("PERCENT", "Percent"), ("AMOUNT", "Amount")],
                default="AMOUNT",
                max_length=20,
            ),
        ),
    ]
```

when i migrate,i get the same description i stated earlier `'manage.py makemigrations'`  and when i makemigration, the same migration file is created over and over even though i have already migrated..is this a #bug
here is the penalty model

```py
class PenaltyModel(models.Model):
    tenant_penalty_desc = models.TextField(null=False)
    tenant_penalty_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)
    tenant_penalty_percentage = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    tenant_penalty_amount = models.FloatField(default=0)
    tenant_penalty_choice = models.CharField(
        choices=TenantPenaltyChoices.choices,
        max_length=20,
        default=TenantPenaltyChoices.AMOUNT,
    )
    rental_house = models.OneToOneField(HouseModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I had deleted all migrations and recreated them again because i was facing some errors.

Result of running sqlmigrate on the migration specified above

```sql
BEGIN;
--
-- Alter field tenant_penalty_choice on penaltymodel
--
-- (no-op)
COMMIT;
```

Comment: You must apply the migration for it to take effect. Check out Workflow in the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/migrations/#workflow). The workflow is: `manage.py makemigrations; manage.py migrate`.

Comment: Iam doing that,django create duplicate migration files

Comment: Is the migration successful? Have you verified its success in the database?

Comment: show us an example of duplicate migrations and referenced model

Comment: Share your `PenaltyModel`.

Comment: @iklinac,the same migration added above is recreated over and over again where the third references the 2nd etc

Comment: What is `TenantPenaltyChoices.choices` ? May it be a function? Could it be that a change is detected in each call of makemigrations? Could you try to assign something constant like a tuple list?

Answer (score 0):

you are right @erny..the issue was i was using

```py
class TenantPenaltyChoices(models.Choices):
    PERCENT = "PERCENT"
    AMOUNT = "AMOUNT"

instead of 
class TenantPenaltyChoices(models.TextChoices):
    PERCENT = "PERCENT"
    AMOUNT = "AMOUNT"
```